# Typo3: How to handle multi-domain in a development environment

Tags: typo3-8.x

I have a website with multiple domains (each domain has its own tree). On the live server everything is fine, but when I develop on localhost I have a problem: 
I cannot (pre)view any pages from the other domain leafs.

```
Website1
    www.domain1.com
    localhost
Website2
    www.domain2.com
```

The above domain records allow me to view all pages of Website1 - but when I want to see a page from Website2, I am redirected to www.domain2.com

e.g. //localhost/?id=100 redirects to //www.domain2.com/?id=100 which results in a 404 of course, because the page is not part of Website1 tree.

I am not able to enter localhost as a domain record for BOTH website roots.
Of course I could install virtual hosts on my local server, but this seems not convenient - I hope there is better solution.

---

**EDIT:**

When I add the language id to my URL, it works:
//localhost/?id=100&**L=0**

:-o

Answer (score 0):

Localhost says to me: you have a local copy of the Website.

If so: disable all domain records, add
config.baseURL >
config.absPrefix >
To your root settings. I guess one or both of  them are set.

Christian